# Want to install OS from USB instead of CD : How to deal with *.img image files?

Tags: windows, iso-image, livecd, bootable-media

I'm on windows.

I'm trying DragonflyBSD operating system. as you can see here: http://www.dragonflybsd.org/download/ there are two kinds of images CD (*.iso) and USB (*.img) files available for download.

I downloaded *.iso and using UNetbootin to make a bootable USB stick. But its taking hell lot of time. Its been 2 hours and its just 50% done(9k of 18k files). I'm really mad now!

I used *.iso because I didn't know how to deal with *.img files. Will it be quick *.img file? How to use it to make bootable USB?

Comment: what does windows have to do with this?

Comment: @smoknheap : 
most of the articles & tutorials on net are giving me a solution but from linux. I don't have linux. I'm on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Win32 Disk Imager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImgFiles#Windows) or the other solution for Windows in the linked article. The article is for Ubuntu but the process of writing an img file to a USB stick is the same.